# python does not connect to local XMPP server

Tags: python, xmpp, ejabberd

i'm trying to connect my local XMPP server by the code coming below

```
import xmpp
client = xmpp.Client('localhost',debug=[])
client.connect(server=('localhost',5222))
```

but i always get this message :

> An error occurred while looking up _xmpp-client._tcp.localhost

i've checked that the port 5222 is already opened(by using telnet).
(i have to mention that the firewall on the localhost is off)
now what should i add to this code to make it work ?

Comment: I have used [link](https://github.com/fritzy/SleekXMPP) SleekXMPP for this sort of thing before, might be worth a look if you can't get this working, SleekXMPP is very well documented with worked examples.

Comment: Are you sure that's not just a warning?  You might actually be connected.

Comment: because it's not working by the way

Answer (score 4):

This message (a warning, not an error as pointed out in xinox's answer) is indicating that a DNS SRV record lookup failed. DNS SRV records are used to find services that are associated with a certain domain (eg. `localhost` in this case, so not really a domain at all which is why the lookup is failing), but which delegate their responsibility to a server living somewhere else.

For instance, if I have a server at `example.net`, making my Jabber ID (JID): `user@example.net`, but my XMPP server lived at `chat.example.net` I could construct an SRV record on `example.net` to point to `chat.example.net`. There are other ways to delegate responsibility, but this is the preferred one. XMPPs use of SRV records is defined in [RFC 6120 §3.2.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6120#section-3.2).

To actually get rid of this error you can use the `use_srv` kwarg, making your initial example:

```
import xmpp
client = xmpp.Client('localhost',debug=[])
client.connect(server=('localhost',5222), use_srv=False)
```

Comment: Note that SRV is not mandatory for XMPP to work (e.g. if your server and accounts live on the same domain), but this warning is produced anyway.

Comment: Yes, that's why it's a warning and not an error (although I personally think warnings are a waste of time and shouldn't be logged at all since they inherently indicate that "nothing went wrong, everythihng is fine")

Answer (score 0):

use this.

```
client = xmpp.Client('127.0.0.1',debug=[])
client.connect(server=('127.0.0.1',5222))
```

or your IP 192.X.X.X